# How to add separators between UITableView sections?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'm implementing a tableview, which has 3 sections(section count remain static) and each section contain several rows.

**Behaviour 1:** Add section header to only the third section.

***How did I achieve:***

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if section == 2 {
       //create and return header view
    }
    return UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: tableView.width, height: UIScreen.main.scale))
}
```

**Behaviour 2:** TableViewCells shouldn't have separator. But, Sections should be separated with a thin line. (similar to tableviewcell separator)

***What did I try:***

- Add a one pixel height, tableView width UIView, with all required properties set(color, etc) and add it as a sub-view to the section header view's
- Add drop shadow with CGPoint(0,1) to the section header views

None of them worked out.

***How did I achieve this:***

1. Find last cell in every section,
2. Create an UIView with 1px height, tableView's width and add it as a subview to the last cell

Though this seem to work. I feel, there must be a better way of doing this, rather than adding line to bottom of every section's last tableView cell. Does anyone know a better way of implementing such behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for adding "section separator lines" and a head view *only* on the 3rd section:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    // if it's the 3rd section, return a view with desired content for the section header
    if section == 2 {
        let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 30))
        v.backgroundColor = .yellow
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 8.0, y: 4.0, width: v.bounds.size.width - 16.0, height: v.bounds.size.height - 8.0))
        label.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        label.text = "Header for Third Section"
        v.addSubview(label)
        return v
    }
    // not the 3rd section, so don't return a view
    return nil
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    // if it's the 3rd section
    if section == 2 {
        return 30
    }
    return 0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    // UIView with darkGray background for section-separators as Section Footer
    let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 1))
    v.backgroundColor = .darkGray
    return v
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    // Section Footer height
    return 1.0
}
```

Comment: It really worked. thanks!! I'd like to understand about the autoresizingMask property. Why do we need to set that?

Comment: Best way to understand it is to play with it. Add a background color to the label in the header: `label.backgroundColor = .cyan` so you can see its frame ... then comment-out the `label.autoresizingMask =` line ... When you run the app, you'll see the label frame is inset from the full header view frame. Now, rotate the device. Without the `.autoresizingMask` setting, the label does not "auto-size" to the new width of the table. You could alternatively use constraints -- and if it's a complex header, that's likely what you'd want to do.

Answer (score 4):

Using `heightForHeaderInSection` method of `UITableViewDelegate` and return section wise height as per you want

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if section == 2 {
            return 1 // return height as per your requirement
        }
        return 0 // return height as per your requirement
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Set the Style of the Table View to **Grouped**: [image]

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution of this Just add the footer view inside the tableview.Set height of the footer view to be a specific height.

Swift:

```
 public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.grey
    return view
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 10
}
```

Comment: This is working fine!